# Ошибка компиляции программы на QT

Tags: c++, c, qt5, qmake, qt6

Прошу помочь со сборкой программы написанной через QT creator (v.6.0.2
Based on Qt 5.15.3 (GCC 11.2.0, 64 bit)), устанавливала его через WSL2.
В самом редакторе сборка осуществляется без проблем, но при попытке сборки через терминал появляются ошибки компиляции, после запуска makefile, скомпилированного через qmake.

```
calculator.cpp: In constructor ‘Calculator::Calculator(QWidget*)’:
calculator.cpp:19:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘Calculator::connect(QButtonGroup*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, Calculator*, void (Calculator::*)(QAbstractButton*))’
   19 |     connect(ui->digits, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   20 |               &::Calculator::digit_numbers);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:242:43: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  242 |     static inline QMetaObject::Connection connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal,
      |                                           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:242:43: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:19:12: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func1’
   19 |     connect(ui->digits, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   20 |               &::Calculator::digit_numbers);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:274:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<((int)(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount) >= 0), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, Func2)’
  274 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:274:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:19:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
   19 |     connect(ui->digits, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   20 |               &::Calculator::digit_numbers);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:283:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<(((int)(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount) >= 0) && (! QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::IsPointerToMemberFunction)), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const QObject*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  283 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, const QObject *context, Func2 slot,
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:283:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:19:12: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func1’
   19 |     connect(ui->digits, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   20 |               &::Calculator::digit_numbers);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:314:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount == -1), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, Func2
’
  314 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:314:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:19:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
   19 |     connect(ui->digits, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   20 |               &::Calculator::digit_numbers);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:322:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount == -1), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const QObject*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  322 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, const QObject *context, Func2 slot,
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:322:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:19:12: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func1’
   19 |     connect(ui->digits, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   20 |               &::Calculator::digit_numbers);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:222:36: note: candidate: ‘static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  222 |     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal,
      |                                    ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:222:79: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const char*’
  222 |     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal,
      |                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:225:36: note: candidate: ‘static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  225 |     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const QMetaMethod &signal,
      |                                    ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:225:86: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const QMetaMethod&’
  225 |     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const QMetaMethod &signal,
      |                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:481:32: note: candidate: ‘QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const’
  481 | inline QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *asender, const char *asignal,
      |                                ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:481:85: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const char*’
  481 | inline QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *asender, const char *asignal,
      |                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
calculator.cpp:21:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘Calculator::connect(QButtonGroup*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, Calculator*, void (Calculator::*)(QAbstractButton*))’
   21 |     connect(ui->arithmetic, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   22 |               &::Calculator::arithmetic);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:242:43: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  242 |     static inline QMetaObject::Connection connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal,
      |                                           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:242:43: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:21:12: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func1’
   21 |     connect(ui->arithmetic, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   22 |               &::Calculator::arithmetic);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:274:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<((int)(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount) >= 0), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, Func2)’
  274 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:274:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:21:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
   21 |     connect(ui->arithmetic, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   22 |               &::Calculator::arithmetic);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:283:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<(((int)(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount) >= 0) && (! QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::IsPointerToMemberFunction)), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const QObject*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  283 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, const QObject *context, Func2 slot,
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:283:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:21:12: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func1’
   21 |     connect(ui->arithmetic, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   22 |               &::Calculator::arithmetic);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:314:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount == -1), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, Func2
’
  314 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:314:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:21:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
   21 |     connect(ui->arithmetic, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   22 |               &::Calculator::arithmetic);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:322:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount == -1), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const QObject*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  322 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, const QObject *context, Func2 slot,
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:322:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:21:12: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func1’
   21 |     connect(ui->arithmetic, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   22 |               &::Calculator::arithmetic);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:222:36: note: candidate: ‘static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  222 |     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal,
      |                                    ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:222:79: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const char*’
  222 |     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal,
      |                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:225:36: note: candidate: ‘static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  225 |     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const QMetaMethod &signal,
      |                                    ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:225:86: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const QMetaMethod&’
  225 |     static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const QMetaMethod &signal,
      |                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:481:32: note: candidate: ‘QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const’
  481 | inline QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *asender, const char *asignal,
      |                                ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:481:85: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const char*’
  481 | inline QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *asender, const char *asignal,
      |                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
calculator.cpp:23:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘Calculator::connect(QButtonGroup*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, Calculator*, void (Calculator::*)(QAbstractButton*))’
   23 |     connect(ui->functions, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   24 |               &::Calculator::functions);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:242:43: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  242 |     static inline QMetaObject::Connection connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal,
      |                                           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:242:43: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:23:12: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func1’
   23 |     connect(ui->functions, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   24 |               &::Calculator::functions);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:274:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<((int)(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount) >= 0), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, Func2)’
  274 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:274:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:23:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
   23 |     connect(ui->functions, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   24 |               &::Calculator::functions);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:283:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<(((int)(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount) >= 0) && (! QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::IsPointerToMemberFunction)), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, const QObject*, Func2, Qt::ConnectionType)’
  283 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, const QObject *context, Func2 slot,
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:283:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:23:12: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func1’
   23 |     connect(ui->functions, &QButtonGroup::buttonClicked, this,
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   24 |               &::Calculator::functions);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/qicon.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractbutton.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets/QAbstractButton:1,
                 from calculator.h:4,
                 from calculator.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:314:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func1, class Func2> static typename std::enable_if<(QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount == -1), QMetaObject::Connection>::type QObject::connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func>::Object*, Func1, Func2
’
  314 |             connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
      |             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:314:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
calculator.cpp:23:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
  
 
make: *** [Makefile:402: calculator.o] Error 1
```

Компилирую через qmake *.pro и дальше make.

Comment: приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример

Comment: А разве не нужно вначале конвертировать UI интерфейсы в компилируемый код?